# Custom setting count vs the license sfdc limits

Tags: limits, licenses

I have a question for which I'm not finding an answer on Web. 
I have a "
**Force.com Enterprise App" licence** where I have the limit of 10 custom objects, I don't understand if 
in such limit are count also the custom settings or just the custom objects (not custom setting)?

Thank in advance... 
Best regards,
Klodjan Meta

Comment: While custom settings are a type of custom object, I don't believe they count towards this limit, because they are designed to store configuration data, not user data. However, I'd let someone from salesforce answer this officially before accepting my word on the matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal users can't see custom settings and there's no way to make them visible/hidden by Profile, you'd have to expose them on Visualforce page for example. I believe the Profile is what matters in determining to which objects user with that license has access to.

So I'd say that unless Profile related to this license type can tick ["Customize application"](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cs_about.htm) I wouldn't worry too much.I don't know about this license type but I've just checked "Force.com - Free User" standard Profile and it lacks "Customize application", "View all data"... It has "view setup and configuration" though.

Comment: Ok, you are right, we had a feedback from salesforce. The count of custom objects is determined by the profile.
Tnks.

Answer (score 0):

As I know Salesforce count custom settings against limit of Sobjects - as the custom settings is a special type of custom object